# How to fail the selenium test suite when a test fails?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

suppose the testng.xml (which is the test suite) file contains 100 tests. How could the the test suite be failed at the occurrence of 1st failure?

Answer (score 1):

as far as I know, unit tests are meant to be independent - and TestNG is unit test framework. THats why TestNG are executing all of your test cases. If you want to fail test suite after first test fail, you will have to use another feature of TestNG - test dependencies

[testNG test dependent-methods](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#dependent-methods)

```
@Test 
public void serverStartedOk() {} 

@Test(dependsOnMethods = { "serverStartedOk" }) 

public void method1() {}
```

This is example of hard test dependency. But still, best practice is to make your test methods independent.

Answer (score 0):

You can also used another way by using `Assert.assertTrue();` or False.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

For reasons which I won't go into, I'd advise against implementing something that fails the suite on the first failure.

However, if I were to build something like this I would likely accomplish it via a method listener which implements `IInvokedMethodListener`

Once, I detect a failure in `afterInvocation()`, I would then immediately start forcefully failing all subsequent tests in `beforeInvocation()`.

Javadocs for IInvokedMethodListener are at - http://testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/IInvokedMethodListener.html

An example implementation might look like this;

```
public class SuiteFailingInvokedMethodListener implements IInvokedMethodListener {
    private static volatile boolean failing;

    public SuiteFailingInvokedMethodListener() {
        failing = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeInvocation(IInvokedMethod method, ITestResult testResult) {
        if (failing) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Test skipped due to a detected failure in the overall suite.");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterInvocation(IInvokedMethod method, ITestResult testResult) {
        if (! testResult.isSuccess()) {
            failing = true;
        }

        //Update the test Result with "Skipped".  
        //Alternatively, you could use omit this code.
        //The RuntimeException thrown above will mark the test with "Failed" by default.
        if ((failing) && 
                (testResult.getThrowable().getMessage().contains("Test skipped"))) {
            testResult.setStatus(ITestResult.SKIP);
        }
    }

}
```

Once you have this listener, you wire it to your suite by adding a line like this in the suite.xml

```
 <listeners>
  <listener class-name="org.mycompany.listeners.SuiteFailingInvokedMethodListener" />
 </listeners>
```